# "Failed with exit code 2" Error when attempting to install python package

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio

I'm a new user of Python (and fairly new to coding as a whole). I'm attempting to install the package TOBIAS and ran the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/loosolab/TOBIAS.git
cd TOBIAS
py setup.py install
```

However, when I try to run the last command, I get the following

```
error message: 
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Microsoft Visual Studio and adding C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64 directly to PATH as recommended here, but I still get this error message.

Any help would be appreciated!! Happy to provide additional info if needed!

Comment: What if you tried PyCharm? Perhaps that will avoid the problem altogether. The virtual environments and dependencies handlin is very easy there. It might save you a couple of headaches.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I was looking into using PyCharm and then realized that the error seems to be for a pretty simple reason all along-- the package is made for Linux systems while I was using a PC. It seems to work now once I've installed the Linus Windows subsystem by executing the

wsl --install

command from the Command Prompt.